# RWeka: how to pass arguments to BayesNet for specific search method

Tags: r, weka

I'm trying to solve simple problem. How to pass arguments to specific search method in RWeka package using BayesNet. Here is code example:

```
BNet <- make_Weka_classifier("weka/classifiers/bayes/BayesNet")
K2="weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2"
wcontrol <- Weka_control(D=TRUE,Q=list(K2,P=2))
model <- BNet(target~., data=train.df, control=wcontrol)
```

at this point it complains

```
Error in .jcall(classifier, "V", "buildClassifier", instances) :
java.lang.Exception: Can't find class called: weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -P 2
Calls: BNet ... RWeka_build_classifier -> .jcall -> .jcheck -> .Call
```

I know that arguments can be passed via Weka_control, and it works if I just use search method, e.g.

```
wcontrol <- Weka_control(D=T,Q=K2)
```

what it should do is to pass additional -- after K2, since using java command it looks like this:

```
java weka.classifiers.bayes.BayesNet -t iris.arff -D -Q weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -- -P 2
```

I tried to append double dash to K2 definition, but still out of luck.

Does it limitation of RWeka or there is still hidden way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to pass those parameters with

```
wcontrol <- Weka_control(D=TRUE,Q=K2,"--",P=2)
```

See Section 4, Controlling Weka Options in the [RWeka Vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/vignettes/RWeka.pdf)

Comment: Nope, I tried that too and it gives me `Error in .jcall(classifier, "V", "buildClassifier", instances) :
  java.lang.Exception: Can't find class called: weka.classifiers.bayes.net.search.local.K2 -- -P 2
Calls: BNet ... RWeka_build_classifier -> .jcall -> .jcheck -> .Call`

Comment: I explored further this approach and ONLY if I specify all options, e.g. search algorithm followed by estimator choice, then it works. Thanks.